# PHP: replace exact string

Tags: php

I am trying to replace exact string with some other string but all what i have been trying not really work as i need.

Here is my string: `http://test.com/?plus=&quotea=&quoteb=`

I need to replace `quotea=` to `quotea=cat` so that `quoteb` want change.

I tried:

```
preg_replace('/quotea=/', 'quotea='. $parmeter.'', $str, 1);

str_replace( 'quotea=', 'quotea='. $parmeter.'', $str, $i );
```

After i run one of the code the result is:

```
http://test.com/?plus="ea=cat"eb=
```

What i am missing here?

Comment: What isn't working? The str_replace should work if $parameter has a value and $i = 1. Unless what you show as an example is exactly what you have in your code. In that case, you have to assign the result to a variable. For example: _$temp = str_replace( 'quotea=', 'quotea='. $parmeter.'', $str, $i );_

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that if you run it again, you'll end up with quotea=quotea=somevalue

Comment: @SloanThrasher HI, i get this: http://test.com/?plus="ea=cat"eb=

Comment: Which one did you run? preg_replace or str_replace?

Comment: Show the before and after contents of $str

Comment: @SloanThrasher i tried once with preg_replace and once with str_replace

Comment: @SloanThrasher the before and the after is on my question.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Try view source on the resulting page. If it's displaying &quotea, the browser may be interpreting part of that as a special character like &quot; is done with the alternate syntax of &quot. The value may be there, but not visible.

Comment: @SloanThrasher i checked that and the string is the same in view source

Comment: echo the $str, and $param to check, you are giving right value or not, it should work

Comment: Do you have an output handler defined? What does `echo ini_get('output_handler')` print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use preg_replace to change the value of quotea regardless of whether it has a value or not:

```
$str = 'http://test.com/?plus=&quotea=&quoteb=';
$rep = 'cat';

echo preg_replace('/quotea=[^&]*&quoteb/', "quotea=$rep&quoteb", $str);
```

Comment: @user2413244 Post the exact strings you're using. I've tested my answer and it works, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: i have test it with your example and this is what i get.

Comment: See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/162b62ca30472a6bc72391d17c6cb710d4a1f557

Comment: @user2413244 Please check your link, it's pointing to the front page instead of your test.

Comment: yes i know there is no share link there. you can paste the code.

Comment: That's a bug with the phptester.net and not with the code. If you'll try it somewhere else it'll work.

Comment: the problem is that i see the same result on my end. what can make this bug?

Answer (score 0):

`$original_string = str_replace("quotea=", "quotea=$param", $original_string);`